# URL re-write to change site's directory root

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

My hosting plan with Godaddy doesn't support changing the directory root, so I uploaded an .htaccess with some rules to re-write my site's URL

I want to change the directory root from

```
(1)  www.mywebsite.com
```

to

```
(2) www.mywebsite.com/php/frontend/index.php
```

so that when users visit `(1)` they actually see the contents of `(2)`. I also want the Omnibox to read `www.mywebsite.com` instead of `(2)`.

I tried the following rules, but it simply redirects to `(2)`  and STILL displays `(2)`'s URL.

How do I accomplish this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   /  php/frontend/index.php
```

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^ /php/frontend/index.php [L]`

Comment: @RahilWazir Thanks for the help. But I get the following error:Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@surplusbidder.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.